# checkbox onchange function does not work as expected in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, checkbox

I have dynamically generated checkboxes on a page.
I use `onchange` function and it works fine in Firefox:

```
function setActionDate(cb_id,dt_id){
    //alert(cb_id);
    var cbox = document.getElementById(cb_id);
    var ddate= document.getElementById(dt_id);
    alert(cbox.value);
    if (cbox.value == 'Y') {
            ddate.className = "";
            ddate.style.backgroundColor="#ffe6e6";  
            ddate.placeholder = "Select Date";
    } else if (cbox.value == 'N'){
            ddate.value = "";
            ddate.className = "disabled";
            ddate.style.backgroundColor="";
            ddate.placeholder = "";
    }
}
```

I read here that IE treats `onchange` event differently and it is preferably to use `onclick` function. However I absolutely need to use **`oncahnge`** function.
Is there a way to resolve it for IE and Chrome?

Comment: why do you need to us onchange

Comment: We use Oracle Apex API to generate checkboxes and we already have onclick function there, which manages values of checkboxes.
I found a solution to the problem though.
I used setTimeout function and it works great in all browsers.
I am posting correct answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right solution to the problem.
Using setTimeout function solves the issue:

```
function setActionDate(cb_id,dt_id){
    setTimeout(function() { 
    var cbox = document.getElementById(cb_id);
    var ddate= document.getElementById(dt_id);
    alert(cbox.value);
    if (cbox.value == 'Y') {
            ddate.className = "";
            ddate.style.backgroundColor="#ffe6e6";  
            ddate.placeholder = "Select Date";
    } else if (cbox.value == 'N'){
            ddate.value = "";
            ddate.className = "disabled";
            ddate.style.backgroundColor="";
            ddate.placeholder = "";
    }
  },100);
}
```